# Using the static iFrame tab to redirect website directly in a new tab without hyperlink in between

Tags: html

I am using the [Static iFrame tab on Facebook](https://apps.facebook.com/iframehost/?fb_page_id=116508435185776) for the purpose of sending a visitor that clicks on it to a website.
It has the option of redirecting, and does so in the same tab(window). 
I would like it to redirect/open in a new tab.

I have coded it to redirect to the website in a new tab by the ordinary: _Blank In this case one has to (after clicking the app/tab) click the hyperlink for it to redirect to the new tab.

Is there code that redirects without (clicking) a hyperlink and opens in a new tab directly by just clicking the app/tab?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the HTML editor in the tab settings and put this code in

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.open("URL HERE", "_blank");
</script>
```

it will open in a new window, (users must allow pop-ups from facebook and have javascript enabled).